# Report parameter showing in two reports

Tags: business-objects, webi

I have two reports in one doc, the source is relational SQL.

I am using the prompt for the first report, but for the second one, I am not using it.

When I run the second report, it still asks for the prompt, although the query is different in both the reports.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what you are clicking to run the report for which you are not expecting to be prompted for a parameter value?

Comment: in data access , i am just refreshing my report, so when i refresh second report , prompts from first report are showing up

Comment: On the Data Access tab are you clicking the Refresh button or the down arrow next to the Refresh button and then choosing the query you want? The Refresh button will refresh the entire document; all queries.

Answer (score 0):

If by "report" you are referring to report tabs at the bottom of the document, remember the data providers (queries) are not specific to each report tab but to the whole document. Refresh will refresh all data providers, unless you choose otherwise. You could design a different query or group of queries for the content of each report tab and then choose to refresh the query or queries related to only that report tab using the drop down as Isaac recommends. I suggest you name the queries in such a way as to make it clear which queries belong to which report tab. Generally a separate document for each distinct use case is easier, using a publication to group documents. Report tabs are usually variations of the same use case.